# How to excluding printing last character

Tags: awk

I have a file named sample.txt with following contents:

```
Tom    24
Sam    56
Bob    49
```

and using AWK/GAWK, I want output to be as:

```
Tom:24,
Sam:56,
Bob:49
```

When I run

```
awk '{print $1 ":"$2 "," }' sample.txt

Tom:24,
Sam:56,
Bob:49,
```

It also prints "," after 49 in the last line. How do I avoid that last comma ","

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if (1 < NR) print previous ","; previous = $1 ":" $2 } END { print previous }' sample.txt
```

However, awk is intended for record-oriented processing. Inter-record dependencies ought to be avoided—another tool might be better suited for you needs than awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s:%s", sep, $1, $2; sep=",\n"} END{print ""}' file
Tom:24,
Sam:56,
Bob:49
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
$ cat sam.txt
Tom    24
Sam    56
Bob    49

$ perl -a -ne ' $_="$F[0]:$F[1]"; print eof ? "$_\n":"$_,\n"  ' sam.txt
Tom:24,
Sam:56,
Bob:49
```

If your file could fit into memory, then

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' s/[ ]+/:/g; print join(",\n",split) ' sam.txt
Tom:24,
Sam:56,
Bob:49
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk ' { a[NR]=$1 ":" $2 } END { for(i=1;i<NR;i++) { print a[i] "," } print a[NR] } ' 


using the given inputs

$ cat sam.txt
Tom    24
Sam    56
Bob    49

$ awk ' { a[NR]=$1 ":" $2 } END { for(i=1;i<NR;i++) { print a[i] "," } print a[NR] } ' sam.txt
Tom:24,
Sam:56,
Bob:49

$
```